3DS iOS SDK automated test case run issue
We can fetch test case messages and then try to run the frictionless Messages flow test case. In this scenario, we are not able to initiate the transaction instance, and at this point, the application crashes with the below error
Could not cast value of type '()' (0x20625ef58) to 'emvco3ds_ios_framework.ults_Transaction' (0x108d69fd8).

NOTE:
We have tried to wrap the SDK call with a custom class and try to call the init method using the API call.
We have tried to find out whether the request objects or parameters are correct and have tried to run the API through the Postman app but have not been able to get the result and have failed in the process.
We expect someone who can guide us with this and provide us with direction to resolve this issue by providing some pointers like API endpoint with request & response structures.
